# Keyboard and locale

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am looking to buy a new keyboard, but most of the ones I am liking are not available the layout I use.

If, say, I use the proper locale on my computer, does the keyboard layout matter then or not? Because if it does not, I could just paster key stickers so that it matches my target layout and call it a day?

Specifically, if the keyboard's layout is QWERTY and set the computer locale to DE, does a Y press result in a Y or Z?

Comment: The keyboard layout is determined primarily by the OS not the keyboard.  In the example you provide, the labels on the keys would be wrong, since the physical product is advertised for a specific layout.

Comment: You could buy a keyboard where you can swap the keys around ;)

Answer (score 1):

To actually answer your question, the DE locale with a QWERTY keyboard would result in a Z appearing when Y was pressed.

The locale and physical keyboard layout must be synchronous for the key presses to match the input received by the computer and its programs.

@DavidPostill 's suggestion is a good one, but it may be simpler to filter you searches to the layout you use, or make the shift to the more common QWERTY layout, but that is totally up to you.